# requireJS use require to load text

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

I'm using backbone with requireJS and I have several template files, I would like to use require() to load the templates without passing it in the module definition, for instance inside a login function in the view, I'd want to do somethign like

```
var html = require( ['text!templates/users/login_form.html'] );
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you download the RequireJS `text` plugin? You need to download it and it put it your project before RequireJS can use text resources as dependencies. You can read about it [here](https://github.com/requirejs/text#usage) on the project page and also in their [API documentation](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#text).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can!

```
loginTemplate = require(['text!templates/users/login_form.html'], 
                        function(Template) {
                         return Template;
                        });
```

this should help you :-)

Comment: I try, it returns the require.js obejct

Answer (score 0):

You can do that asking for "require" as a dependency in the module definition

```
define(["require", "other_dependencies"], function(require, etc) {
    var template = require('text!templates/users/login_form.html');
});
```

Comment: Hi thanks, it does works however when I try to use the value it tells me that the resource has been loaded

Comment: has or hasn't been loaded? Are you trying to use "template" variable outside the define function ?